# Cannot authenticate in PostgreSQL DB on plesk

Tags: php, postgresql, plesk

We have just installed the **PostgreSQL** component into **plesk** but we cannot authenticate using the PHP function *@pg_connect()*

```
$connection = @pg_connect("host=localhost port=5432 dbname=my_db_name user=my_user password=my_pwd");
output("Connection: ".$connection);
```

The error is showed in the connection object that is printed:

```
Connection: 
Array
(
    [type] => 2
    [message] => pg_connect(): Unable to connect to PostgreSQL server: FATAL:  Ident authentication failed for user "my_user"
    [file] => path/to/my/script.php
    [line] => 5
)
```

Does anyone tried to use PostgreSQL DB on plesk? Did you use some 'default' username and password ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally we found out that, in Linux, the default installation of PostgreSQL doesn't accept access through network socket connection but only through Unix socket.

So I can connect to DB using the default Unix socket, and the correct **@pg_connect** instruction is:

```
$connection = @pg_connect("host='' port='' dbname=my_db_name user=my_user password=my_pwd");
```

Answer (score 1):

Looks like password for PostgreSQL user "postgres" does not correspond password in psa database.

Try to reset password for PostgreSQL admin user with command:

plesk bin database-server --update-server localhost:5432 -type postgresql -passwd 12345

Comment: Thanks, but we wanted to use an other created user for the DB connection.